# Is there book series for russian learners?

Tags: словоупотребление, resources

There is book series for example for English learners and these books are contains different level books from beginner to upper intermediate.

So is there pdf books in Russian like these ?

Comment: Put in a link for what the book series in English looks like. Otherwise your question sounds very vague, almost like "are there a series of textbooks for learning Russian at different levels," to which the answer is obviously "yes."

Comment: Should books are you looking for be available gratis?

Comment: I didnt want to mention a company name but I mean book series like penguin readers and I prefer it free.

Comment: You could've written 'adapted literature book series' or 'readers.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

http://shop.redkalinka.com/en/9-books-with-audio

Comment: No.Same like at the below but only for Russian.

http://www.penguinreaders.com/members/pr/students/download-area.html

Answer (score -3):

Check these two!

[Russian essential grammar and conversational language](http://amzn.to/2hxs0Ln)

[Russian language in 25 lessons](http://amzn.to/2id6RH6)

Comment: please avoid self-promotion, at least it worth to mention that you are recommending book written by you. It's  next to spam and spam is something not tolerated here.